# Recognize Bitcoin address from block hash, and transaction hash

Tags: blockchain.info, php

I'm building a block explorer using blockchain.info and their API
https://github.com/blockchain/api-v1-client-php/blob/master/docs/blockexplorer.md

but what I don't understand is, what is the best way to recognize if the user is searching for an address or a block hash, or what ever.
how do the other block explorers do that?
They allow to search for all of those in the same search box.

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Block explorers I've seen typically accept the following inputs:

- Bitcoin address: [25-34 alphanumeric characters](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_version_1_Bitcoin_addresses).
- Block height: decimal number, up to let's say 10 digits
- Block hash: 64 hex digits (0-9, a-f), representing a 256-bit number
- Transaction ID: 64 hex digits

So it's easy to recognize a Bitcoin address or block height with a simple regex.

They can't tell apart a block hash from a transaction ID, because in principle any given 256-bit number could be the hash of either (or neither).  So when a string of 64 hex digits is input, they simply search for it as block hash *and* as a transaction ID, and if one of them is found, they return the appropriate information.  It's overwhelmingly improbable that the same string could be the hash of a valid block and of a valid transaction, so there isn't really any need to handle the possibility that both are found.

They could do some minor optimizations: for instance, if the string starts with a bunch of zeros, it's more likely to be a block hash, so maybe they search that table first.

Comment: Í would like to, if I may, to add to first bullet point: when on production, addresses begin with „1“ or „3“ ...